# htaccess 301 redirect rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm looking for help with making a `301` redirect for:

`www.domain.com/word/*` to `www.domain.com/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?word/(.*) http://sitename.com/$1
```

Comment: Hi How can you also make this work without the "/"after word?

Comment: So www.domain.com/word to www.domain.com

Comment: Tried that but then domain.com/word/xyz goes to domain.com//xyz with two "//"

Comment: Ok it worked. Just used:
 RewriteRule ^/?word(.*) http://www.sitename.com$1 [L,R=301]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect 301 /word /
```